# How to cut off four corners of ImageView in android

Tags: java, android, xml, imageview

I have to fix a rectangular image into a diamond shape transparent image and want to cut off extra four corners of rectangular image. please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

create a xml file in ur drawable folder and writ the code

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


<item>
<shape android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
</shape>
</item>

<item android:left="1dp" android:right="1dp"  android:top="1dp"  
    android:bottom="1dp">
<shape android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    <stroke android:width="10dp" android:color="@android:color/white" />
 <corners
 android:bottomRightRadius="1dp"
 android:bottomLeftRadius="1dp"
 android:topLeftRadius="1dp"
 android:topRightRadius="1dp"/>
</shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: after creating XML, where to put it?